# Parsley validation for group of elements in a form is not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms, parsley.js

I am using `Parsley.js` for validating a form submission for one of my projects.

I have two panels with single submit button in each panel. When the submit button is clicked, I require to validate only that panel element not other panel elements. For that I used the attached code which is in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxc90wtw/1).

Comment: This is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxc90wtw/1/

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer: [Validate set of fields only if radio button is checked (conditional validation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002630/validate-set-of-fields-only-if-radio-button-is-checked-conditional-validation) which details the usage of `data-parsley-group`.

In short it won't work. This is because Parsley requires all `data-parsley-group` fields to be validated before the form `$.submit` event is triggered.

You have two options to accomplish what you are trying:

1. Create two separate forms. Each one has its fields and its submit button. Simpler and better way.
2. You would have to do something like this: [ParlseyJS - remove validation from disabled fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282967/parlseyjs-remove-validation-from-disabled-fields). That is, when the user clicks the submit button, you will have to set the fields of the other panel as disabled, destroy parsley and apply parsley.

Comment: I am developing my project in ASP.NET and it doesn't permit us to make two separate forms and the other one is also difficult to implement that is every time removing of the attribute is fairly difficult and complex, hence I was choosing some other solution which is possible using your v1.Thank you for your response.

Comment: By composing the script in the way as like in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ch1Lm6bv/, I have been overcome the above problem.Please tell me whether it is a right approach or not.@milz