# HTML problem with validation radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make the conditional validation for the radio button, as shown below.

[image]

I want to have the query 16 and 17 inactive upon selected "Yes".

I tried this approach:

[Validate set of fields only if radio button is checked (conditional validation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002630/validate-set-of-fields-only-if-radio-button-is-checked-conditional-validation)

http://jsfiddle.net/milz/tbw22L59/8/

which looks promising for me. Unfortunately, after application to my code, it doesn't work. I tried it on one query so far

**HTML:**

```
                             <figure class="fig">
                                    <label>
                                        <div class="order">15</div>
                                        <p>Scheme managed block<span class="asterisk">&#42; </span></p>
                                    </label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input id="op_managed_block_yes" name="scheme_managed_block" class="radiobtn" type="radio" value="Yes" required>Yes
                                    <input id="op_managed_block_no" name="scheme_managed_block" class="radiobtn" type="radio" value="No">No 
                                    <br>
                                </figure>
                                <figure class="fig" id="op_manager_on_site">
                                    <label>
                                        <div class="order">16</div>
                                        <p>If Yes is Scheme Manager on-site<span class="asterisk">&#42;</span></p>
                                    </label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input name="if_yes_is_scheme_manager_on-site" class="radiobtn" type="radio">Yes
                                    <input name="if_yes_is_scheme_manager_on-site" class="radiobtn" type="radio">No 
                                    <br>
                                </figure>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  <script>
                                         $("input[name=scheme_managed_block]").on('click', function() {
                                    var managerOnSite = $('#op_manager_on_site');
                                    // if is company
                                        if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                                            // show panel
                                            managerOnSite.show();

                                            // remove disabled prop
                                            managerOnSite.find('input,select,radio').prop('disabled', false);
                                        } else {
                                            // if is not company, hide the panel and add disabled prop
                                            managerOnSite.hide();
                                            managerOnSite.find('input,select,radio').prop('disabled', true);
                                        }
                                    });
                                </script>
```

the script is placed just underneath the HTML code.

Where is the mistake then?

Comment: Are you using `parsley.js`?

Comment: yes I have it included